# Get all weeknums from 2 input dates and put them in an array?

Tags: excel, vba, date

Since I asked a wrong question in the last post, but still improved a lot (I already created a Planning table in Excel, if someone want it I will be happy to share), here is what im trying do to: **Cell B2: Start Date** and **Cell B3: End Date**

Example: 
B2 --> 11/03/2019
B3 --> 22/04/2019

[image]

Here is my code so far with the help of this community

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()

Dim sDate As Date, eDate As Date
Dim NoOfWeeks As Long
Dim arr As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim myCellToStart As Range
Set myCellToStart = Worksheets(1).Range("D4")

Dim myVar As Variant
Dim myCell As Range
Set myCell = myCellToStart

With Worksheets("Foglio1")
    sDate = .Range("B2")

    If Weekday(sDate, vbMonday) <> 1 Then
        sDate = DateAdd("d", 7 - Weekday(sDate, vbMonday) + 1, sDate)
        NoOfWeeks = 1
    End If

    eDate = .Range("B3")
End With

If sDate = eDate Then
    NoOfWeeks = NoOfWeeks + 1
Else
    NoOfWeeks = NoOfWeeks + WorksheetFunction.RoundUp((eDate - sDate) / 7, 0)
End If

ReDim arr(1 To NoOfWeeks)
For i = 1 To NoOfWeeks
    arr(i) = i
Next i

End Sub
```

Basically with my current code I would obtain an array with this ouput: **arr(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)**

Related to this --> [See Calendar](https://www.epochconverter.com/weeks/2019)

I would like to obtain: **arr(11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17)**

Comment: Insetad of `arr(i) = i` use `arr(i) = i + Application.Worksheetfunction.WeekNum(sDate)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `Application.WeekNum` will be much more simple:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

    Dim StartDate As Date, EndDate As Date

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Foglio1") 'remember to fully qualify your ranges, including the workbook
        StartDate = .Range("B2")
        EndDate = .Range("B3")
    End With

    Dim StartWeek As Long, EndWeek As Long
    StartWeek = Application.WeekNum(StartDate, 2)
    EndWeek = Application.WeekNum(EndDate, 2)

    Dim arr
    Dim i As Long
    ReDim arr(StartWeek To EndWeek)
    For i = StartWeek To EndWeek
        arr(i) = i
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Very nice, upvoted! Only small comment is that OP uses `vbMonday` (or rather 2) Leaving that out would default to 1 if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Wow, very clean and easy to understamd. I don't need an IT teacher, this community is someting beatiful :)

Comment: A little comment if I can. How to make Monday, first day of the week. By your code week starts on Sunday, if I'm not wrong.

Comment: @ChangeWorld like JvdV well pointed out you just need to add the `vbMonday` or `2` like this: `Application.WeekNum(StartDate, vbMonday)`

Answer (score 3):

This is an alternative way:

[image]

```
Sub Test()

Dim StrtD As Long, EndD As Long
Dim arr As Variant

With Sheets("Foglio1")
    StrtD = Application.WeekNum(.Cells(1, 2).Value, 2)
    EndD = Application.WeekNum(.Cells(2, 2).Value, 2)
    arr = Application.Transpose(.Evaluate("ROW(" & StrtD & ":" & EndD & ")"))
End With

End Sub
```

The `Application.Transpose()` creates an 1-D array you can call through `arr(x)` where x is any position within the array. You can leave the transpose if you want to create a 2-D array.

---

To not use `.Transpose` but use `.Columns` to return a 1-D array you can tweak the code to:

```
Sub Test()

Dim StrtD As Long, EndD As Long
Dim arr As Variant

With Sheets("Foglio1")
    StrtD = Application.WeekNum(.Cells(1, 2).Value, 2)
    EndD = Application.WeekNum(.Cells(2, 2).Value, 2)
    arr = .Evaluate("COLUMN(" & .Cells(1, StrtD ).Address & ":" & .Cells(1, EndD ).Address & ")")
End With

End Sub
```

I guess it's a matter of preference as both ways will return an array > `arr(11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17)`

Comment: Nice, alternative with `Application.Transpose()`, I will take note :) +1

Comment: "The `Application.Transpose()` creates an 1-D array you can call through arr(x) where x is any position within the array. You can leave the transpose if you want to create a 2-D array." I don't get this JvdV, doesn't the application transpose create a 2D array always?

Comment: @Damian, `arr = .Evaluate("ROW(" & StrtD & ":" & EndD & ")")` will return a 2-D array e.g. `arr(x,y)` whereas, `Application.Transpose` will transform that into a 1-D array, being `arr(x)`.

Comment: True! I was thinking the other way

Comment: @Damian Transpose swaps rows and columns in an array, but it also happen that if the input array has only one column  the resulting array will be one dimension. Note that using COLUMN instead of ROW will get an 1D array directly.

Comment: @VincentG I tested JvdV's code using COLUMN instead of ROW and it throw a 16384 item's array, 1D array indeed, but something went wrong so bad.

Comment: COLUMN need "A:B" style range, so it is a little more complicated to use. you can try `.Evaluate("COLUMN(" & Chr(64 + StrD) & ":" & Chr(64 + EndD) & ")")`

Comment: And it will stop working (well) after 26, so keeping Row + Transpose is probably better.

Comment: @Damian, I have included a piece of code to demonstrate how to avoid `.Transpose` using `.Column` as per VincentG his comment. As you can see it will get a bit more complicated, however still very much possible.

Comment: I see now JvdV! Instead using the column index that way is using the column letter. Why does Excel behave like that with column index?

Comment: Because ROW and COLUMN are taking ranges references in argument, not coordinates.

Comment: @Damian, I had a good think about it and I could simplify my latest edit down to a better way of getting a 1-D array without transpose. I guess it's up to the user's preference wheather or not to use rows/columns

Comment: Nice alternative, a bit simplier, to me at least, than the one before :)

Comment: Adapted my code to fit the restraint of crossing over to a new year, but since the question wasn't clear about that could occur at first, decided to leave it out. The accepted answer fits the actual question. @ChangeWorld