# Get monthnames between 2 input dates and put them into an array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

Here is what I'm trying to do: **Cell B2: Start Date** and **Cell B3: End Date**

Example: 
B2 --> 01/01/2019 
B3 --> 01/05/2019

Example

[image]

Here is my code so far:

```
Sub GetUniqueMonths()

Dim StartDate As Date, EndDate As Date

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Foglio1") 'remember to fully qualify your ranges, including the workbook
    StartDate = .Range("B2")
    EndDate = .Range("B3")
End With

Dim StartWeek As String, EndWeek As String
StartWeek = MonthName(Month(StartDate))
EndWeek = MonthName(Month(EndDate))

Dim arr() As String
Dim i As Long
ReDim arr(StartWeek To EndWeek)
For i = StartWeek To EndWeek
    arr(i) = i
Next

End Sub
```

I would like to loop thought the given two dates: **01/01/2019** and **01/05/2019** get the month names and put them in the array **arr**, but all I get it's an error --> **type mismatch** on `ReDim arr(StartWeek To EndWeek)`, any suggestions?

My output would be **arr(January, February, March, April, May)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could answer this in the same fashion as I did this morning on [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57866293/9758194). Just as an alternative try:

[image]

```
Sub Test()

Dim StrtD As Long, EndD As Long
Dim arr As Variant

With Sheets("Foglio1")
    StrtD = Month(.Cells(1, 2).Value)
    EndD = Month(.Cells(2, 2).Value)
    arr = Application.Transpose(.Evaluate("TEXT(DATE(2019,ROW(" & StrtD & ":" & EndD & "),1), ""mmmm"")"))
End With

End Sub
```

---

If you go past a span of a certain year you need to know how many months are between two dates. In your example `1-12-2019` and `1-3-2020`. Now the formula I used in `.Evaluate` will need to get a range from 12-15. We can use `DateDiff` function for that, see below:

```
Sub Test()

Dim StrtD As Long, EndD As Long
Dim arr As Variant

With Sheets("Foglio1")
    StrtD = Month(.Cells(1, 2).Value)
    EndD = StrtD + DateDiff("m", .Cells(1, 2).Value, .Cells(2, 2).Value)
    arr = Application.Transpose(.Evaluate("TEXT(DATE(2019,ROW(" & StrtD & ":" & EndD & "),1), ""mmmm"")"))
End With

End Sub
```

You might wonder "but now you feed the formula a range of 12:15? How would that return the right month since it doesn't go past 12?" Well, the nice thing is that the formula will know that with 13 we meant January, with 14 we meant february etc. Therefor the correct array is returned to the variable. :)

Comment: @ChangeWorld, all I do is mimic a worksheet array function to pull in the month names through .Evaluate into the array at once. It might look a bit intimidating, but once you start reading the line properly, recognize the formula I used it will start making sense.

Comment: Was trying to improve your code with `.Transpose` but it seems like it works only for 1 year... I mean if i put `Start date: 01/12/2019` and `End date: 01/03/2020` It will return only `December`, it only count 1 year, that is because in the formula you put `2019`?

Comment: That's because you feed the formula twice a 1 for start and end month. I'll update the answer to make it a bit clear on how to make it work :) @ChangeWorld

Comment: Ok thank you, because I didn't understand what is **That's because you feed the formula twice a 1 for start and end month**

Comment: @ChangeWorld, never mind that specific line. The problem was that the range of rows we feed the formula would be croocked if you pass the span of a year. That's now fixed in the answer ;)

Comment: Wow! Another question and I will let you go :). Can I use DateDiff also for WeekNum function?

Comment: It sure does work for [weeks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/datediff-function) too @ChangeWorld, I assume the above worked for you now?

Comment: It worked for half I mean, because it created me and infinite months and my Excel crashed. But I will debug it no problem. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199304/discussion-between-changeworld-and-jvdv).

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
Option Explicit
Sub GetUniqueMonths()

    Dim StartDate As Date, EndDate As Date

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Foglio1") 'remember to fully qualify your ranges, including the workbook
        StartDate = .Range("B2")
        EndDate = .Range("B3")
    End With

    Dim StartWeek As Long, EndWeek As Long
    StartWeek = Month(StartDate)
    EndWeek = Month(EndDate)

    Dim arr() As String
    Dim i As Long
    ReDim arr(StartWeek To EndWeek)
    For i = StartWeek To EndWeek
        arr(i) = MonthName(i)
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> ReDim arr(StartWeek To EndWeek)
> ```

The `ReDim` statement wants to know what the new array lower/upper bounds are going to be: it fully expects numeric values for this...

> ```
> Dim StartWeek As String, EndWeek As String
> StartWeek = MonthName(Month(StartDate))
> EndWeek = MonthName(Month(EndDate))
> ```

...but you're giving it a `String` for the lower bound, and another `String` for the upper bound - hence the *type mismatch*: you want these to be `Long` integer values, not month names.

```
Dim StartWeek As Long, EndWeek As Long
StartWeek = Month(StartDate)
EndWeek = Month(EndDate)
```

That said, `StartWeek` and `EndWeek` are pretty misleading names to use for something that's actually holding `StartMonth` and `EndMonth` values.

Use the `MonthName` function at the last minute, when you need to turn the numeric month# into a *month name* - also, it's a good habit to never hard-code `For` loop boundaries when iterating an array, even when the boundaries are plain obvious:

```
For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    arr(i) = MonthName(i)
Next
```

Note that you should probably validate the inputs:

> ```
> With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Foglio1") 'remember to fully qualify your ranges, including the workbook
>     StartDate = .Range("B2")
>     EndDate = .Range("B3")
> End With
> ```

If the `StartDate` is greater than the `EndDate`, expect issues. Best make that assumption explicit:

```
'execution stops here if assumption is wrong:
Debug.Assert StartDate <= EndDate
```

Or plainly raise an error:

```
If StartDate > EndDate Then Err.Raise 5, "GetUniqueMonths", "Invalid date range"
```

Or flip the inputs to make them valid:

```
If StartDate > EndDate Then
    Dim tmpDate As Date
    tmpDate = StartDate
    StartDate = EndDate
    EndDate = tmpDate
    Debug.Print "Flipped user inputs; StartDate > EndDate."
End If
```

Since the dates are coming from a worksheet, consider using *data validation* to make sure `StartDate <= EndDate` - then, a `Debug.Assert` call to should suffice to validate.

Comment: OP was asking before for week numbers... so this code is the one I gave him for such goal, he just changed it a bit I guess.

Comment: @Damian I'm not sure where weeks come into play, given "My output would be arr(January, February, March, April, May)" =)

Comment: From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57865429/7558682) OP just adapted the code I think.

Comment: @ChangeWorld read what Mathieu wrote, you need numerics to dimension an array. He also added an error handler in case someone missplace the dates.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Great explanation! Nice tip to plain raise an error if the `Start Date` is greater than the `End Date`