# How to fill an array of week numbers that restarts at week 1 after week 52?

Tags: excel, vba, week-number

In **Cell B2: Start Date** and **Cell B3: End Date**

Example: 
B2 --> 01/12/2019 
B3 --> 03/02/2020

[image]

My code

```
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Foglio1") 'remember to fully qualify your ranges, including the workbook
        StartDate = .Range("B2")
        EndDate = .Range("B3")
    End With

    Dim StrtD As Long, EndD As Long
    Dim provaprova As Integer

    With Sheets("Foglio1")
        StrtD = Application.WeekNum(StartDate, 2)
        provaprova = DateDiff("w", StartDate, EndDate)
        EndD = StrtD + provaprova
        arr = .Evaluate("COLUMN(" & .Cells(1, StrtD).Address & ":" & .Cells(1, EndD).Address & ")")
```

My output: **arr(48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58)**
I would like: **arr(48,  49, 50, 51, 52, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)**

Since the year **has 52 weeks**, I would like **week 1** after **week 52**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer will be based on our discussion and is very closely related to both [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57865283/9758194) question on weeknumbers and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57872845/9758194) one on months.

The problem here is that the timespan crosses over into a new year. Therefor I'll adapt my answer on the months to fit my answer on the week's question:

So please try:

[image]

```
Sub Test()

Dim StartD As Long, EndD As Long, EndW As Long
Dim arr As Variant

With Sheets("Foglio1")
    StartD = .Cells(1, 2).Value - Application.Weekday(.Cells(1, 2).Value, 2)
    EndD = .Cells(2, 2).Value - Application.Weekday(.Cells(2, 2).Value, 2) + 7
    EndW = DateDiff("ww", StartD, EndD)
    arr = Application.Transpose(.Evaluate("WEEKNUM(" & StartD & "+(ROW(1:" & EndW & ")*7),2)"))
End With

End Sub
```

Which will return an array of `48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6`.

It was a little difficult to work with `DateDiff` in this case as sometimes it wouldn't take whole weeks between dates depending how many days in a week are still left. However, looking at the first days of a week will tackle that.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Yeah this one returnes the proper array. Flawless answer.

Comment: Note that on your question 2-2-2020 with vbMonday is actually week 5, so the 6 in your desired output should be excluded!

Comment: Ah, sorry was cheking code, and thought I wrote **03/02/2020**, I will update it right away! thanks

Comment: You should update your answer too, because week 6 should be excluded! :)